# php function_exists then ceases to exist

Tags: php, wordpress

A plugin I'm using to move a wordpress install checks `function_exists('mysqli_connect')`.

In the installer this check comes up as a failure, but from the command line `php -r 'echo function_exists("mysqli_connect")?"pass":"fail"; echo "\n";'` outputs `pass`.

What could be causing the function `mysqli_connect` to cease to exist?

I'm using php7.2, and I verified that is the running script with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: You may have either: 1) Multiple PHP installations 2) PHP-FPM needs to be restarted 3) Different php.ini files for CLI and your webserver (which means you need to turn on the extension in your webserver php.ini)

Comment: That was it. I just needed to restart apache. Can you answer so I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical causes of this are 1 or more of the following:

- Multiple PHP Installations. (CLI is 1, web-server is using another)
- Apache/Nginx/PHP-FPM needs to be restarted (Typically a config file was updated but the related service(s) weren't restarted)
- You have different `php.ini` files for CLI and your webserver (which means you need to turn on the extension in your web-server's `php.ini`)